# UINavigationController back button problem in landscape mode?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

my iphone application supports portrait mode earlier, now i want to support land scape mode also.

everything is working fine in my application except the navigation controller back button.
i have used tableviews in navigaton conroller, when i click back button in landscape mode view is getting poped and its loading its previous view but animation is strange.

i have given default animation but, in landscape mode view is is animating upside down instead of default left to rite when i click back button.

does anyone faced this kind of problem???
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i understood the problem and below is the solution...
each viewcontroller which i am pushing into navigation controllers should have the following delegate method.

each view controller should confirm that it is supporting the orientation change

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  self.orientation = interfaceOrientation;
  return YES;
  }