# IPad ViewController pop animation style changed from sliding from right to left to sliding from bottom to top

Tags: ios, ipad

The animation of pop view controller in iPad is changed unexpectedly from sliding from right to left to sliding from bottom only in Landscape mode. What could be the problem ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: need to see some code to diagnose the problem. Please paste in your popViewController code

Comment: Fixed. UIController should implement -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation

Comment: Thank you any way @Peter Andersen

Comment: The same problem is also asked here (with the solution ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045925/uinavigationcontroller-back-button-problem-in-landscape-mode

Comment: so this is closed. Thank everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me when I was supporting landscape and portrait, but on the viewcontrollers "supportedInterfaceOrientations" method I was returning "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait"

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

This fixed it for me:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```